# Fatal error at Ubuntu VM run

Tags: 20.04, virtualization

I have installed VM on my Windows 8, but FATAL error has occurred . How can I fix it, what's wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu version 12.04? Please add the version number in your question.

Comment: I have a flash disk with ubuntu instalation but i do not know the version. I believe it is 20.04

Comment: Looks like you neglected to insert the Ubuntu install .iso file into the Virtualbox virtual CD drive. It's a common first-time oversight for folks who didn't check out any of the many great Virtualbox tutorials or quite well-written documentation.

Comment: @user535733 Right, how can I fix it ? How can I insert it.. I have my iso on the flash disk.

Comment: @user535733 I a complete beginner to VM. Could you give me a hint where my virtual CD is at best via a picture. I definitely do not orient myself at help and videos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @user535733 has mentioned, you've likely not loaded the installation ISO file. Looking at the screenshots, it looks like you may have *several* issues that will need to be resolved before you can install Ubuntu:

1. the system memory is insufficient for Ubuntu Desktop (but okay for Ubuntu Server)
2. the video memory is insufficient for Ubuntu Desktop (but okay for Ubuntu Server)
3. the storage space (1.49 GB) is insufficient for any modern version of Linux
4. the network adapter may be better set as "Bridged"

So, with this in mind, let's go through the process of creating a VirtualBox installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 from scratch. Many of these steps you've likely already done but, if this is your first Ubuntu VM, it may be good to double-check.

1. Open VirtualBox (if it's not already open)
2. Create a new Virtual Machine by pressing "New" (or the equivalent thereof)
3. Give the VM a descriptive name and ensure it is set to "Linux" and "Ubuntu (64-bit)":
   [image: Check the settings]
4. Give the VM at least 2GB of RAM. Ubuntu Server can run with less, but 2GB is a good start:
   [image: Set the Memory]

   You can always change this later if needs be.
5. For the storage, choose "Create a virtual hard disk now" and press "Create":
   [image: Make some storage]
6. Choose "VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image)", then "Dynamically Allocated". This will ensure the disk image does not instantly use all the space you will assign.
7. Set the amount of storage to a number greater than 25GB:
   [image: File location and size]

   **Note:** Because the disk image is dynamic, it will not use all this space immediately. It is simply a maximum.
8. Press "Create"

Now the basics are in place for the VM, but you will need to make a couple of changes:

[image: VirtualBox Overview]

1. Press the "Settings" icon (with the gear) and choose "System" from the left-side menu. Set the "Processor" to a good number of CPUs, with 2 being  good number for a simple VM:
   [image: Processor]

   Checking "Enable PAE/NX" may be worthwhile, but not a requirement.
2. Under Storage, mount the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO that you downloaded to the CD:
   [image: Mount CD]

   You will need to use the `.iso` file, not a flash disk with the ISO "burned" to it. If you don't have the ISO, you can [download one from Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/server).

   Ensure "Live CD/DVD" is checked:
   [image: Live CD]
3. For Audio, feel free to disable it if you are running Ubuntu Server
4. Under Network, select "Bridged Adapter" so that the VM connects to your network. Click "Advanced", then choose "Allow All" under the "Promiscuous Mode" setting. This will make it easier for you to use the VM like a normal server on your network:
   [image: Network Settings]
5. Press "OK" to close the settings panel. The other settings can be left as they are for now. You can tweak them later if you wish.

Now that the basic settings are done, you're ready to press "Start" and install Ubuntu Server:

[image: Install Ubuntu Server]

Welcome to Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Considering all the work you put into this fabulous answer, you might consider adding it as an answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328 also. And perhaps to tutorials.ubuntu.com also.

Comment: Evrything works fine, but how can I install **most of** existing packages, the editor Joe and perl among them, automatically ?

Comment: According to Canonical, there are [over 60,000 packages](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management) that can be installed. Not sure if you want to install *most* of them. That said, if there is a specific package (or packages) that you would like, feel free to create a new question, as that would be a separate topic from this one 

Comment: buntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install -y joe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package joe
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$

Comment: @matigo I can only post every 40 minutes so please wait.

Comment: @matigo [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389200/how-can-i-install-joe-on-vm-ubuntu) it is.