# How can I install `joe` on VM ubuntu?

Tags: apt, 20.10, text-editor

I was trying to instal `joe` editor on my newly created VM Ubuntu but it fails.

```
buntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install -y joe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package joe
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Have you enabled the `universe` repository?

Comment: @steeldriver No. How can I enable it ?

Comment: If you really have fresh installation of 20.10, then it should be noted that it is EOL. Reinstall supported release - 20.04 LTS or 21.10 instead. About Joe - it is available from `joe` and `joe-jupp` [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=joe). So you need to run `sudo apt-get update` on supported Ubuntu release followed by `sudo apt-get install joe` or `sudo apt-get install joe-jupp` .

Comment: See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Also ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt) is worth a read.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 3):

Joe is part of [the universe repository](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/joe_4.6-1build2_amd64.deb.html), so you will need to first enable that via the console:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Once this is done, update `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now you can install Joe:

```
sudo apt install joe
```

Comment: Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy-security InRelease
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/…ntu groovy Release' no longer

Comment: Some error copied above occurs.

Comment: Umm … Groovy Gorilla is an EOL release of Ubuntu. You’ll need to use 18.04, 20.04, or 21.10 if you would like to install packages 

Comment: Can I update my instalation or shall I undergoe the heavy path with installing my Ubuntu ?

Comment: It’s no longer possible to upgrade from 20.10, so you’ll need to download a supported ISO from Ubuntu.com and follow the same steps as you did earlier today to build the VM. Consider it practise 